# Flex download progressbar never fires INIT_COMPLETE event

Tags: apache-flex

I have a class extending the DownloadProgressBar in my project. most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes for some users that already have the player in their cache its getting stuck on the "INIT_PROGRESS" phase and INIT_COMPLETE never fires.

im adding the events listeners by overriding the set preload function using:

```
preloader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, myHandleProgress);   
preloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myHandleComplete);
preloader.addEventListener(FlexEvent.INIT_PROGRESS, myHandleInitProgress);
preloader.addEventListener(FlexEvent.INIT_COMPLETE, myHandleInitEnd);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

which sdk you use?

we also custom the DownloadProgressBar and works ok(using SDK3.5)

Comment: im using sdk version 4.5.